# Calculating Job finish time

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-arithmetic

So `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` has start time and some integers out of which you can calculate an end time

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time))+
        CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( run_duration AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') ) As JobFinishTime
 FROM  msdb.dbo.sysjobs j  
 INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h ON j.job_id = h.job_id  
 where h.step_id = 0 AND h.run_status=1 AND j.enabled = 1  
 AND  j.enabled = 1
```

so one of my jobs has run_duration value of 250910, which is 25 hours, 9 minutes, 10 seconds. Obviously conversion fails since it is more than 24 hours. Can you please help me fix above query when value of run_duration is 250910

Use this as reference, filled run_date and run_time with some values

```
select CONVERT(datetime, msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(20230411, 70358))+
        CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( 250910 AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') )
```

Comment: As you've noticed `run_duration` is neither a `time` nor a `datetime` data type. Have you considered just converting it to seconds and letting the presentation layer deal with giving it formatting? If instead you're wanting the actual job finish time then calculate duration in seconds and use `dateadd()` to offset the `run_time`.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#example)? That table's datetime representation is beyond ridiculous, but at least they gave an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you have a start date and a duration expressed as a string in 'HHMMSS' format, from which you want to derive an end date. One approach uses string functions to separate the hours, minutes and seconds, convert the whole thing to a number of seconds, and then offset the start date with `dateadd()`.

Assuming that you have the start date in column `jobStartTime` and the duration in `runDuration`, you could express this like:

```
dateadd(
    second, 
    left(runDuration, 2) * 60 * 60 + substring(runDuration, 3, 2) * 60 + right(runDuration, 2),
    jobStartTime
) JobFinishTime
```

Here is a contrived example:

```
select x.*, 
    dateadd(
        second, 
        left(duration, 2) * 60 * 60 + substring(duration, 3, 2) * 60 + right(duration, 2),
        startdt
    ) enddt
from ( values (getdate(), '250910')) as x(startdt, duration)
```

| startdt | duration | enddt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-02 13:34:12.203 | 250910 | 2023-05-03 14:43:22.203 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y0rOPv-4)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to extract active job that have lasted more than 24 hours

```
SELECT sj.name
,  sja.start_execution_date,
DATEDIFF(minute,sja.start_execution_date,getdate())  as Runtime
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS sja
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS sj ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL
and DATEDIFF(minute,sja.start_execution_date,getdate())>=24
```

History Job:

```
SELECT j.Name, jh.Step_name,

CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM(jh.run_date)) 
+ ((jh.run_time/10000 * 3600) 
+ ((jh.run_time%10000)/100*60) +
(jh.run_time%10000)%100 ) / (23.999999*3600 )
AS Start_DateTime
,jh.run_duration,

CONVERT(DATETIME, 
RTRIM(jh.run_date)) + ((jh.run_time/10000 * 3600) + ((jh.run_time%10000)/100*60) +
(jh.run_time%10000)%100) / (86399.9964)
+ ((jh.run_duration/10000 * 3600) + ((jh.run_duration%10000)/100*60) + (jh.run_duration%10000)%100
) / (86399.9964) AS End_DateTime

from msdb..sysjobhistory jh, msdb..sysjobs j
where jh.job_id=j.job_id
--and j.name = ‘Job_name’
ORDER BY run_date desc, run_time desc
```